# How parameter is working in single line expression of arrow function in useState function

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

```
 const tick = () => {
     setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1);
        
       // setCount(count+1);
    }
```

My question is from where prevCount variable is getting it's initial value?
How the expression supplied to setCount() is working?

I have created a react example to explain.

[React js example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pgzn6p), please refer tick function in interval.jsx component.

Update:
As per a comment by [Dennis Vash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7882470/dennis-vash) on my question I am supplying callback function to setCount() then Why it does not work if I write it like this?

```
   const tick = () => {
           setCount(updateCount(count))
            
           // setCount(count+1);
        }

     const updateCount = (myCount) => {
        return myCount + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Please read the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: @jonrsharpe Now I somewhat understand, but still confused that what does this mean "The function will receive the previous value", from where does the variable prevCount is getting it's value?

Comment: Where does any function gets its parameters from? They're passed in when it's called, by the React implementation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, here I am calling setCount(), and I have not defined prevCount anywhere?
Maybe I am missing some conceptual understanding here.

Comment: What do you mean you haven't defined it? It's what you named the parameter. This is nothing to do with React, it's just ES6 arrow function syntax.

Comment: Its not related to React, read about callback functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `setCount` function from `useState` hook. which is itself a React inbuilt function.

So `setCount` is a function that accepts a function as a call back function.
Your code

```
setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1);
```

Let's simplify it for you

```
setCount(function(prevCount) {
    return prevCount+1
})
```

So here you can see that `setCount` accepts a function which will be called back as the last step of execution of the `setCount` function, at that time setCount will pass a previous value of the state variable as an argument to the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

the Arrow function works like this,

For single parameter brackets optional, 
`prevCount => prevCount+1` -> `function(prevCount){return prevCount+1}`
`(prevCount) => prevCount+1` -> `function(prevCount){return prevCount+1}`

And for multiple parameters You need to add braket,
`(prevCount, a, b, c) => prevCount+1` -> `function(prevCount, a, b, c){return prevCount+1}`

And for empty parameter You need to add empty brackets,
`() => prevCount+1` -> `function(prevCount){return prevCount+1}`

For more info read, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)'s doc

## UPDATE:

here in your updated question, `updateCount(count)` is getting called directly. So use something like this,

```
setCount(updateCount)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an update.
If I write code like this  setCount(previousCount => updateCount(previousCount)) then it works. Still does not understand that what previousCount variable here is? I mean I don't get it that from from where previousCount variable which I passed as paramter is getting it's value from?

Comment: @Harsimer  the parameter is the current state, checkout https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html